# What is the latest version of Xcode which is compatible with Mac OS X v10.6.2 and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, osx-snow-leopard, installation, xcode

I have Xcode 3.1.3 on Mac OS X 10.5.8 on a MacBook Pro and I want to upgrade from Leopard to Snow Leopard. What Xcode version is compatible with Snow Leopard and how do I install it? Give me some guidelines.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350283/snow-leopard-and-xcode-3-1

Comment: Snow Leopard is the latest commercial release of Mac OS X. Update to the latest minor version (10.6.6) and run the latest Xcode version and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode comes free with Mac OS X, so anytime you buy a new set of installer DVDs for a new version of Mac OS X, it comes with the version of Xcode that was up-to-date as of the time that version of Mac OS X was released. Xcode isn't installed by default, and it often packaged on a separate DVD disc in the same box.

But the Xcode team never sits still, so at any given time, there's a good chance there's a  later version of Xcode on the [Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/mac/). You have to be a registered developer to get it, but registration is free and easy, and Xcode updates are free once you've registered.

At the time of this writing, the latest Xcode on developer.apple.com is 3.2.3, with iPhone SDK 4.

I follow many indie Mac/iPhone developers on blogs and twitter, and it seems most of them stay on top of the latest Xcode releases as soon as they come out.

By the way, the latest version of Mac OS X is 10.6.4, not 10.6.2. If your Snow Leopard installer DVD's have an earlier version, don't worry, just run Software Updates right after you install Snow Leopard and let it get the latest updates.